# Time complexity of finding a triangle in undirected graph

Tags: java

Recently I posted the following [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521126/determine-if-a-graph-contains-a-triangle/31522980#31522980) on Stack Overflow and comments made me to rethink about the time complexity of my solution which I am sure is \$O(V+E)\$. Please suggest reasons as to why I am wrong.

```
import java.util.*;
class Triangle
{
 static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g; 
 static int []visited;
 static int []level;
 static int []parent;
 static Queue<Integer> q=new LinkedList<Integer>();
 public static void create_graph()
 {
     int n,i,k,j;
     Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("enter the value of number of vertices");
     n=s.nextInt();
     visited=new int[n];
     level=new int[n];
     parent=new int[n];
     for(i=0;i<n;++i)
      {visited[i]=0;level[i]=-1;}
     g=new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
     for(i=0;i<n;++i)
     {
         g.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
         System.out.println("enter the number of vertices adjacent to "+ (i)+" and what are they?" );         
         k=s.nextInt();
         for(j=1;j<=k;++j)
           g.get(i).add(s.nextInt());
     }      
 } 
 public static boolean BFS(int so,int l)
 {  
        int i;   
        visited[so]=1;
        q.add(so);
        level[so]=l;
        while(q.size()!=0)
        {
            i=q.poll();            
            for(int e:g.get(i))
             {
                if(visited[e]==0)
                {visited[e]=1;
                 level[e]=level[i]+1;                 
                 q.add(e);
                 parent[e]=i;
                }
                else if(level[e]==level[i]&&parent[e]==parent[i])
                 return true;
             }
        }
        return false;          
 }
 public static void main(String []args)
 {
      int so,i;      
      Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
      create_graph();
      if(BFS(0,0))
       System.out.println("The graph contains a triangle");
      else  System.out.println("The graph does not contain a triangle");      
 }
}
```

Comment: I believe your algorithm runs in \$O(V+E)\$ time.  But it may not find all solutions.  See [this stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10193372/4192931) for a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

Before I'll get to your timecomplexity let me tell you something:

### Your code screams for a lint:

> ```
> class Triangle
> {
>  static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g;
> ```

this part should become:

```
class Triangle {
    static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> g;
```

no wait scratch that:

1. Whenever possible - specify visibility
2. Program against interfaces
3. Use speaking variables

Okay let's try again

```
public class Triangle {
    private static List<List<Integer>> graph;
```

same goes for your `int[]`s. On a very related note, you should encapsulate state into a class and not into the static context, where everything can modify it. Drop the static modifiers you use.

Use the `final` keyword to signal immutability. Use it wherever possible to reduce risk of misassigning variables.

The initialization blocks become:

```
private final List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
private int[] visited;
private int[] level;
private int[] parent;
private final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

---

I usually prefer to add an empty line before a method head to help in recognizing it as new method. And also respect Java naming conventions for method names. This means: no snake_case and no SHOUTCASE. camelCase is the way to go:

```
public void createGraph() {
```

Also respect the braces placement of Java conventions. On a related note keep nice spacing around your operators. Cramping code together doesn't help readabiltiy and the times of scarce memory, where every unnecessary space was a wasted Byte are over:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner();
```

is preferrable over:

> ```
> Scanner s=new Scanner();
> ```

same goes for all the operations you're doing...

While we're at Scanner. One of these Scanners is not used, neither is ever closed. Close your resources with `try-with-resources`, remove all of your unused variables and declare variables as close as possible to their usage.

This gets rid of:

```
int so, i;
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
int n,i,k,j;
```

To make things clear, this is what your code looks like in my IDE right now:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Triangle {

    private final List<List<Integer>> graph = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    private int[] visited;
    private int[] level;
    private int[] parent;
    private final Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public void createGraph() {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("enter the value of number of vertices");
            int vertexCount = scanner.nextInt();
            visited = new int[vertexCount];
            level = new int[vertexCount];
            parent = new int[vertexCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
                visited[i] = 0;
                level[i] = -1;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; ++i) {
                graph.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
                System.out.println("enter the number of vertices adjacent to " + (i) + " and what are they?");
                int k = scanner.nextInt();
                for (int j = 1; j <= k; ++j) {
                    graph.get(i).add(scanner.nextInt());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean triangleCheck(int so, int l) {
        visited[so] = 1;
        queue.add(so);
        level[so] = l;
        while (queue.size() != 0) {
            int i = queue.poll();
            for (int e : graph.get(i)) {
                if (visited[e] == 0) {
                    visited[e] = 1;
                    level[e] = level[i] + 1;
                    queue.add(e);
                    parent[e] = i;
                }
                else if (level[e] == level[i] && parent[e] == parent[i])
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Triangle tri = new Triangle();
        tri.createGraph();
        if (tri.triangleCheck(0, 0)) {
            System.out.println("The graph contains a triangle");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("The graph does not contain a triangle");
        }
    }
}
```

---

By now you're probably asking yourself "Why did I even come here, I wanted to know about time-complexity"... The answer is. I couldn't even understand your code until just now.

Honestly I still now have problems, bit I think you should get down to   \$O(V)\$, under the assumption that this code actually produces correct results..